# MS Access query producing an unexpected result (illustrated)

Tags: sql, ms-access, boolean-logic

(Disclaimer: No real names in this database. Database is from a tutorial offered free online by GCF [Goodwill Community Foundation, a respected organization] [Database source](https://media.gcflearnfree.org/content/56f06139c87fa620e88dccb6_03_21_2016/access2016_sampledatabase.accdb))

Below is a subset of the original database which should be sufficient for the purposes of the problem here:

| First Name | Last Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | Hinton | Cary |
| Amaya | Gibson | Raleigh |
| Danny | Haverford | Raleigh |
| Dick | Whitman | Raleigh |
| Denver | Ferguson | Raleigh |
| Don | Hamm | Cary |
| Alix | Mars | Raleigh |
| Dwyane | James | Cary |
| Dwight | Parker | Raleigh |
| Andrew | Bedinger | Raleigh |
| Dane | Raught | Raleigh |
| Andrzej | Wujek | Raleigh |
| Alyssa | Ullman | Raleigh |
| David | Barrett | Raleigh |
| Anisa | Naser | Raleigh |
| Avery | Kelly | Raleigh |
| Derek | MacDonald | Chapel Hill |
| Alex | Yuen | Cary |
| David | Barrett | Raleigh |

I'm getting an unexpected result in a database query.

I know I'm doing something wrong. I need your advice on what I'm doing wrong.

**Part 1: this works**

The query below works as expected.

**(update)** in Plain English: "give me firstname, last name, city where ((first name starts with "a" and city is "raleigh") OR (where first name starts with "d" and city is not "chapel hill"))"

**(update)** the SQL from the SQL view is:

Query:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**Part 2: this doesn't work**

**(update)** in Plain English: "give me first name, last name, city where ((first name starts with "a" and city is "raleigh") OR (where first name starts with "d" and city is not "chapel hill") OR (where first name starts with "d" and city is not "cary")"

In the query below, I'm still seeing results from the cities "Chapel Hill" and "Cary". So it is not working as expected.

Query:

```
SELECT Customers.[First Name], Customers.[Last Name], Customers.City
FROM Customers
WHERE (((Customers.[First Name]) Like "a*") AND ((Customers.City)="raleigh")) OR (((Customers.[First Name]) Like "d*") AND (Not (Customers.City)="raleigh")) OR (((Customers.[First Name]) Like "d*") AND (Not (Customers.City)="cary"));
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong in Part 2?**

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**: I've understood the problem. The "NOT" is unintuitive. The query is working fine. It's just that I assumed that it won't show "Chapel Hill" or "Cary" in the result. But the reason these are showing up in the result is because the `Not "chapel hill"` is causing Cary to show, and the `Not "cary"` is causing "Chapel Hill" to show

Comment: Most here will not download files. All info to analyze issue should be posted in question. Provide sample data as formatted table and/or DDL. Can post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide db there.

Comment: Edit question to show SQL statements as text. Clarify the filter rules. You want where: `([First Name] LIKE "a*" AND City ="raleigh") OR ([First Name] LIKE "d*" AND NOT City IN("chapel hill", "cary"))`? Are there other cities than these 3 in data?

Comment: @June7 good question regarding cities other than 3. For people whose names start with "d", there are only these 3 cities. My SQL isn't so good, but I've written out a Plain English version of each query above it. It should clarify what I'm seeking here.

Comment: @June7 I've added a table containing a relevant subset of the original database. This table should be enough for understanding the problem in my post. Thank you for suggesting this.

Comment: Did you try my suggested criteria? Switch to SQL View and type or copy/paste there.

Comment: @June7 I think I've understood the problem now. The "NOT" throws off the results in unexpected ways. I've pasted the SQL (obtained as you suggested) now.

Comment: Well, you haven't used my suggestion. The copy/paste I meant was to copy my suggested criteria and paste it into your SQL.

Comment: @June7 My concern was in trying to understand why what I was doing wasn't working. Not to find the solution. I know a couple of other ways to solve it. It's just that I expected what I was doing here to also work. But I understand now why it won't work.

Comment: Okay, if Andre's answer resolves your issue, please mark accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've understood the problem. The "NOT" was unintuitive to me. The query is working fine. It's just that I assumed that it won't show "Chapel Hill" or "Cary" in the result. But the reason these are showing up in the result is because the Not "chapel hill" is causing Cary to show, and the Not "cary" is causing "Chapel Hill" to show.

Comment: Which is what I wrote in my answer... `(a AND NOT x) OR (a AND NOT y)` cancel each other out. All cities will be in the result, not just the two.

Answer (score 1):

It does exactly what it's supposed to do.
Your 2nd and 3rd line are basically

```
(LIKE d* AND NOT foo) OR (LIKE d* AND NOT bar)
```

With [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws) :

```
Distributivity of ∧ over ∨:   x ∧ ( y ∨ z ) = ( x ∧ y ) ∨ ( x ∧ z )
```

this becomes:

```
LIKE d* AND (NOT foo OR NOT bar) =
LIKE d* AND NOT (foo AND bar) =
LIKE d* AND NOT False =
LIKE d* AND True =
LIKE d*
```

So the d* lines aren't filtering for city at all.

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but it is most probably easier to formulate in SQL, where you can freely put parentheses around AND and OR, instead of the graphical query editor.